# SQL Server foreign key constraint - pair (same tuple)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, constraints

Suppose these 2 tables:

**tbl1**

```
ID
name
fkID1
fkID2
```

**tbl2**

```
ID
pkID1
pkID2
```

Whenever data is inserted into `tbl1`, how can I ensure `(fkID1, fkID2)` exists as a row (tuple) in `tbl2` in the form `(pkID1, pkID2)`?

I have no problem making a constraint so `fkID1` must exist and that `fkID2` must exist but I want to ensure they exist in the same row.

Either via SQL or instructions to create it via management studio would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just comma delimit the columns you want to check. Just make sure they're in order.

```
alter table tbl1 with check 
add constraint FK_tbl1_tbl2 
foreign key (fkID1, fkID2) 
references tbl2 (pkID1, pkID2)
```

Comment: I have a little problem outwith this question: `pkID1` is a FK itself in tbl2 and `pkID2` is not a key at all. SQL returns `There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table`. What can I do to solve this? Could I make `pkID1` and pkID2` the PK in tbl2? How would the existing relationship work with `pkID1` being a FK to say `tbl3`?

Comment: New question here, very related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733548/foreign-key-in-composite-primary-key