# Foreign key in composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key, constraints

I have the following 3 tables:

**tblA**

```
ID - PK
name
```

**tblB**

```
ID - PK
tblAID - FK references tblA.ID
pkID2
```

**tblC**

```
ID - PK
tblAID *
fkID2 *
...
```

I want to make this tuple a FK of `(tblB.tblAID, tblB.pkID2)`

If I do this:

```
alter table tblC with check 
add constraint FK_tblC_tblB 
foreign key (tblAID, fkID2) 
references tblB (tblAID, pkID2)
```

I get an error message:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'tblB'
>   that match the referencing column list in the foreign key
>   'FK_tblC_tblB'

I.e.: I want to ensure that the tuple pair inserted into `tblC` exists in `tblB`. But I cannot do that as `pkID2` is not a key. Really `tblB` could have `tblAID, pkID2` as a composite primary key. But then `tblAID` would still have to be a FK of `tblA.ID`.

Comment: This is half rhetorical but why can't the columns you're putting into tblC just go into tblB?

Comment: I am not clear on what you are trying to accomlish. Is the purpose of this constraint to prevent adding rows to tblC unless tblB contains like tblAID and pkID2 values and prevent deletions from tblB when tblC contains like tblAID and pkID2 values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Really tblB could have tblAID, pkID2 as a composite primary key.

Or create a new unique key from these two fields. A foreign key does not need to refer to a primary key.

> But then tblAID would still have to be a FK of tblA.ID.

That will still work. A column in a primary or unique key can also participate in other constraints, including foreign key constraints.

Comment: So what would you suggest, adding a new UNIQUE KEY for `tblAID, pkID2`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am suggesting.

Comment: @IgorK: Exactly. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188066.aspx.